# How to get occurence number of a recurrent meeting from the EWS using c#?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Below is the link for modifying and deleting occurrence of a recurrence meeting.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633618(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633618%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

My question is how we can get the occurrence number from ews or is there any way to find it.

```
Appointment occurrence = Appointment.BindToOccurrence(service, new ItemId(sRecurringMasterId), 3);
```

In the above code they have hard coded occurrence number as 3, but how i can get this info dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way , what I do is the following:

1. Get the appointment which as the RecurringMaster.
2. Define the Start and Ending time for the recurrence, if there is no
   end time , like it goes forever, then I define a number of days
   which I would search within
3. Find appontments based on the previous timings
4. Filter the results based on the type AppointmentType.Occurrence, and
   count what you got

The Following code explains what I have written above.

```
var occurrencesCounter = 0;  
if (appointment.AppointmentType == AppointmentType.RecurringMaster) 
{ 
    appointments = ppointment.Service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new CalendarView(appointment.Start, (appointment.Recurrence.EndDate == null ? DateTime.Today.AddDays(7) : (DateTime)appointment.Recurrence.EndDate)));
    foreach (var apt in appointments)
    {
        if (apt.AppointmentType == AppointmentType.Occurrence)
        {
            occurrencesCounter++;
        }
    } 
}
```